# notepad++ bookmark lines containing numbers between

Tags: text, macros, notepad++

I have a big file, so I put there just few lines, that it will be more understandable.

I have notepad++ file:

```
14  TOP:   0.12      2.7   -11.1    13      0.14      2.8   -11.1    13
15  TOP:   0.00      8.4   -81.7    13      0.32      2.5     1.6    13
16  TOP:   0.00      8.7  -114.8    13      0.60      3.0    13.6    13
17  TOP:   0.00      1.9  -113.7    13      0.33      3.2    -2.7    13
18  TOP:   0.00     -1.7  -112.7    13      0.28      2.7    -2.1    13
19  TOP:   0.00     -2.7  -119.5    13      0.22      2.1    -1.1    13
20  TOP:   0.00     -2.6  -130.7    13      0.23     -2.0    -0.6    15
21  TOP:   0.00     -2.4  -143.6    13      0.23     -2.1    -0.5    15
22  TOP:   0.00     -2.1  -157.8    13      0.23     -2.1    -0.8    15
23  TOP:   0.00     -2.0  -175.3    13      0.21     -2.0    -1.4    15
24  TOP:   0.00     -1.8  -199.7    13      0.20      2.1    -2.6    13
25  TOP:   0.00     -1.1  -236.6    13      0.22      2.4    -3.5    13
26  TOP:   0.00      0.5  -289.6    13      0.29      2.7    -1.8    13
27  TOP:   0.00      2.7  -351.0    13      0.53      2.8    11.1    13
```

I need to bookmark lines with number in front 16 to 18, 21 to 26. The result should be:

```
16  TOP:   0.00      8.7  -114.8    13      0.60      3.0    13.6    13
17  TOP:   0.00      1.9  -113.7    13      0.33      3.2    -2.7    13
18  TOP:   0.00     -1.7  -112.7    13      0.28      2.7    -2.1    13
21  TOP:   0.00     -2.4  -143.6    13      0.23     -2.1    -0.5    15
22  TOP:   0.00     -2.1  -157.8    13      0.23     -2.1    -0.8    15
23  TOP:   0.00     -2.0  -175.3    13      0.21     -2.0    -1.4    15
24  TOP:   0.00     -1.8  -199.7    13      0.20      2.1    -2.6    13
25  TOP:   0.00     -1.1  -236.6    13      0.22      2.4    -3.5    13
26  TOP:   0.00      0.5  -289.6    13      0.29      2.7    -1.8    13
```

So maybe have someone an idea how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex `^(?:1[6-8].*|2[1-6].*)` in the box `Find what`.

Go to the last tab (I don't know the english name!)
The checkbox `Regular expression`  must be ... checked
The checkbox `Dot matches newline` must not be checked.

Click the button `Find All`

Comment: Hi, M42, thank you for your answer. The problem is, that it works, but it is too much to write. Let me explain. I have thousands lines, and if I need theses lines 20 to 302 and 612 to 1120 than I should always add 2[..] 3[..] 4[..] and to 30[..]. So maybe is the solution how to write 20 to 302 ant 612 to 1120?

Comment: @unrealliving: I see, so the best way should be writing a script in your favorite language.

Comment: Never done that before. Is it difficult? I know that notepad++ can handle the scripts, but I do not know, how to write it. Maybe some one could help me in writing it?

Comment: @unrealliving: Sorry,I don't know how to write a macro for NP++. Modify a bit your question or ask another one and explain clearly your problem.